# How can I save data from one textView with user defaults to another textView without erasing previous data?

Tags: ios, swift

I can allow the user to pass data from one label to another label without erasing the existing data but I haven't been able to pass User Default data from one textView to another textView.
Must be two completely different things.

Tried, this, that and the other but not what I need for it to work.

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(textView.text, forKey: "data")


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

let viewControllerTwo = ViewControllerTwo()

let passData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "data")

if let data = passData as? String

{

textViewOne.text = data

viewControllerTwo.textViewTwo.text = (viewControllerTwo.textViewTwo.text ?? "") + data
}
```

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewControllerTwo, animated: true)

```
//Have previously used this for labels which works fine.

//label.text = (label.text ?? "") + "NEW TEXT"

//label.text = (label.text ?? "") + "NEW TEXT2"

//Result ⬇️

//label.text = NEW TEXT
//             NEW TEXT2
```

All that happens is the existing text is replaced, I want it to be added.

Comment: In you second vc, if you don't pass any values / push from first vc. Does your textview values is still displaying in your second vc ?

Comment: Not if I push to the new VC at the same time, but if I send User Default data it moves to the new VC. I can then push from a separate function to the new VC and see the data that has been added.

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing the `viewControllerTwo` before the data can be saved. Try moving `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewControllerTwo, animated: true)`
to the end.

Comment: I already put the navigation in a separate function called somewhere else as I don't want to navigate when the UserDefaults is set. Either way it replaces the data.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks , when you push your Firstvc to secondvc, assign one var in secondvc and set the value from Firstvc.

In your **secondVC**

```
var name:String?
```

In your **firstVC** :

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "storyBoardName", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Second vc identifier") as! yoursecondvc
vc.name = "your text"
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Mean while, you needs to save your second vc `textview.text` value in some userdefault.And add the `userdefault values +  new variable`.  Again when ever your screen is getting dissmiss your can save the updated `textview.text` values to your userdefault. I hope it will work. If still you looking more or better way let me know.